# cmake opengl error when building Voxelands

Tags: compiling, opengl, cmake

I am trying to build Voxelands for Ubuntu however I get a `cmake` error that `OpenGL` has failed.

What package do I install so `cmake` can build correctly?

This is my build error:

```
sayth ~/Downloads/voxelands-master-2e653e147710f4b07a7bca4a080b208c13423cba $ cmake -DRUN_IN_PLACE=1 
-- *** Will build version 1704.00 ***
-- IRRLICHT_SOURCE_DIR = 
-- IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR = IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- IRRLICHT_LIBRARY = IRRLICHT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Could NOT find IRRLICHT (missing:  IRRLICHT_LIBRARY IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- gettext msgfmt path: /usr/bin/msgfmt
-- GetText enabled; locales found: ja;vi;nl;pl;hy;fr;ru;ro;hu;it;pt_BR;de;jbo;es;da
-- Sound enabled
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:172 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:110 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sayth/Downloads/voxelands-master-2e653e147710f4b07a7bca4a080b208c13423cba/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 1):

That current error relating to OpenGL is probably due to the missing library `libgl1-mesa-dev`. This can be installed using `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev`.

It also looks like you may have the `libirrlicht-dev` library missing and possibly more.

Looking at the documentation, there are a number of libraries required. It may be worth executing the following:

```
sudo apt install libopenal-dev libvorbis-dev libfreetype6-dev libx11-dev libirrlicht-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libjpeg-dev libbz2-dev
```

That should install all of the required libraries to enable you to build the application.